Balun converting 100ohm single-ended trace to 50ohm single ended for spectrum analyzer
On my board, I have 100ohm differential pair traces connected to a 1:1 balun, so the signal impedance becomes 100ohm single ended.  I would like to measure the signal spectrum with spectrum analyzer.  Can I connect the 100ohm single-ended signal to a 2:1 balun to convert it to 50ohm single-ended for spectrum analyzer?  Thanks.

Your second balun is actually an "un-un" and would usually just be called a transformer :)
So, can you use 2:1 winding rate transformer to convert 100Ω single-ended to 50Ω single-ended?
Not quite, but close: The ratio of input- to output impedance is the square of the ratio of input- to output voltage (which is 2:1 in this case, so you'd get ¼ of 100Ω, 25Ω).
Instead, you'll want a \$\sqrt{2}:1\$ winding transformer (which of course only exists approximately, but seeing that ideal transformers don't exist, either, a 14:10 winding transformer comes already pretty close).


Can I connect the 100ohm single-ended signal to a 2:1 balun to convert
it to 50ohm single-ended for spectrum analyzer?

No, that would make it 25 Ω compatible. The turns ratio squared defines the impedance ratio (step-up or step-down) and, in your case, the turns ratio squared is 4:1 and the impedance would reduce to 25 Ω.
However, if you put your spectrum analyser input in parallel with an extra 50 Ω resistor you can achieve this but, remember that the signal displayed by the analyser will be 3 dB down across the spectrum.
But, why use two cascaded baluns when you can replace the 1:1 balun with a 2:1 (admittedly with a 25 Ω output impedance). Maybe it won't fit the board? Maybe there are other reasons?
Alternatively, ditch the 2:1 balun and use a 50 Ω resistor in series with your spectrum analyser input. You'll still get a loss that you need to compensate for of course.
